# ¿Cómo solucionar este error en Android Studio "Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:20.4.0"?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, cordova, capacitor

Tengo un problema que no pudo solucionar, desarrollando una aplicación en ionic luego de exportarla a android con capacitor, pero me sale el siguiente error al exportar el apk.

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:20.4.0.

Por mucho que intento cambiar las versiones en el build grandle, el error continúa. Sospecho que algún error de versiones de los servicios, sin embargo, al cambiarla sigue saliendo el error, de hecho ya borre la carpeta android y la volví a crear que se genera cone el comando "npx cap add android"